# Expand types of struct fields into variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Say I have a struct like so:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    float b;
    bool c;
};
```

And a templated function like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts> void func();
```

How could I write a function that calls `func()` using Foo's field types, like so: `expand<Foo>(); // will call func<int,float,bool>();`

Comment: The only way I can think of is to have a function that creates a tuple from a `Foo` and then unpacks the tuple in the call to `func`. I don't think you're going to be able to get away with anything simpler than that with current C++ reflection capabilities.

Comment: @Rikus Honey How would I convert the struct to a tuple? That’s the part I care more about.

Comment: You can do ```auto foo_tup = std::make_tuple(some_foo.a, some_foo.b, some_foo.c)``` but I guess you want the compiler to automatically do that for you which brings us back to the original problem.

Comment: Take a look at [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by the snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/utilForever/1a058050b8af3ef46b58bcfa01d5375d).

Some tricks can be done with structured binding in C++17 to achieve simple static reflection. Boost::PFR (or [magic get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) mentioned above) basically use the same technique when C++17 is detected, but I'll provide a simplified implementation if you don't want to import that library:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class... TArgs>
decltype(void(T{std::declval<TArgs>()...}), std::true_type{}) test_is_braces_constructible(int);
template <class, class...>
std::false_type test_is_braces_constructible(...);
template <class T, class... TArgs>
using is_braces_constructible = decltype(test_is_braces_constructible<T, TArgs...>(0));

struct any_type {
  template<class T>
  constexpr operator T(); // non explicit
};

template<typename T, template <typename ...Unused> typename R>
constexpr auto extractTypes() noexcept {
    using Type = std::decay_t<T>;
    Type* tptr;

     if constexpr(is_braces_constructible<Type, any_type, any_type>{}) {
        auto& [ m0, m1 ] = *tptr;
        return R< std::decay_t<decltype(m0)>, std::decay_t<decltype(m1)> > {};
     } else if constexpr(is_braces_constructible<Type, any_type>{}) {
        auto&& [m0] = *tptr;
        return R< std::decay_t<decltype(m0)> > {};
     } else {
        return R<> {};
     }
}
```

`extractTypes()` in the code above accepts an aggregate-initializable Type `T` to reflect, and a variadic template `R` to receive the extracted types. You can put the operations you want to perform on these types inside a struct `R`:

```
template <typename ...Types>
struct R {
    static void doStuffs() {
        (operation<Types>(), ...);
    }
};
```

In the above code, `T` can hold up to 2 members, but you may extend the implementation to support the number of members you want. If you find writing those boilerplate tedious, you can try [this header-only utility](https://github.com/SdtElectronics/ACI/tree/master/reflection) wrote by me. It uses macro to generate the code supporting arbitrary number of members, but requires boost to build.

Answer (score 0):

Implement for `Rikus Honey` idea,
Works with `c++17` or above

if you can have tuple member to your struct with types you need;

you can do like below;

```
   struct Foo 
    {
        std::tuple<int, float, bool> tpl_;
    };

template <class...Ts>
void test( Ts... ) {}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    
    std::apply( []( auto&&...args ) { test( args... ); }, f.tpl_ );

}
```

good point `@user975989`

Comment: Intrusive, but also bloats the struct. You want to keep a copy of every element?

Comment: Yeah, I guess this could work if there’s no better way. I would like if there was a way to define this tuple at compile time though.

Comment: @user975989 the tuple can be static. I don’t actually need to access the elements, just the type info.

Comment: @cry0genic Oh I see, I thought you would want to also access the elements. Seems less bad now, but I can't really see the usage if you don't also care about the elements.